# Identify first column values per ID and operate based on that value

Tags: r

Identify first column values per ID and replace based on that value

I have the following df with many columns:

```
input <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
Obs1 = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1),
Obs2 = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0),
Control1 = c(1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2),
Control2 = c(1,2,2,2,3,1,1,1,2,2))
```

I would like to modify 'Control' columns values. If first 'Obs' value per ID is 0 then, I have to substract -1 to the whole ID group:

```
result <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
Obs1 = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1),
Obs2 = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0),
Control1 = c(1,1,2,2,2,0,1,1,1,1),
Control2 = c(0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2))
```

The way in which I obtained the first obs values per ID is the following one:

```
i <- 1 
aux <- vector("list", 2)

for (i in 2:3)
aux [[i]] <- input[!duplicated(input$ID), i]
```

With this list, how can I modify 'Control' columns? ( I have more than 100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using data.table, I would convert your data first to long format (while merging all the `"Obs"` and `"Control"` columns into same columns using the `patterns` function), do the calculations and convert back to wide. This will scale to any number of pairs.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

# The patterns of the columns we will be working with
cols <- c("Obs", "Control")

res <- 
  # convert to data.table and add row index so we can dcast back afterwards
  setDT(input)[, rowind := .I] %>% 

  # Convert to long format and combine all Obs and Controls into two columns
  melt(., id = c("rowind", "ID"), patterns(cols), value.name = cols) %>%

  # Reduce 1 from Control in case the first value is zero
  .[, Control := Control - first(Obs == 0), by = .(ID, variable)] %>%

  # Convert back to wide format
  dcast(., ID + rowind ~ variable, value.var = cols, sep = "") %>%

  # Remove the row index
  .[, rowind := NULL]

res
#     ID Obs1 Obs2 Control1 Control2
#  1:  1    1    0        1        0
#  2:  1    0    1        1        1
#  3:  1    1    1        2        1
#  4:  1    1    0        2        1
#  5:  1    0    1        2        2
#  6:  2    0    1        0        1
#  7:  2    1    1        1        1
#  8:  3    1    1        1        1
#  9:  3    0    1        1        2
# 10:  3    1    0        2        2
```

Comment: works perfectly under my original df. That was very helpful!